# hibernate + Oracle 11.2 + BLOB

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jdbc, blob

I googled a lot and haven't found working issue... In my web app I need to upload large files using ajax. I use ajaxfileupload plugin for it. In my FormBean class I mapped file to InputStream:

```
private InputStream fileData;
```

and

```
@FormParam("file")
@PartType("application/octet-stream")
@JsonIgnore
public void setFileData(InputStream fileData) {
    this.fileData = fileData;
}
```

It works fine. I can save this stream into a file and haven't got any problems with java heap size. Now I'm trying to save it into database using Hibernate. Like this:

```
repFile.setFileData(session.getLobHelper().createBlob(file.getFileData(), 1024L));
```

and when I save repFile object I have **ORA-01461** can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column.
It works with Oracle 10. But it crashes with Oracle 11.2
I tried to add lobHandler to my configuration - didn't help

```
<property name="lobHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler">
            <property name="nativeJdbcExtractor">
                <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.CommonsDbcpNativeJdbcExtractor"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

And set batch size to 0 and allow steams

```
<prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
```

That didn't help also... does anyone have a solution for this? Any help would be good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the domain class like this:

```
@javax.persistence.Lob
private java.sql.Blob fileData;
```

Also, make sure that you create the column in the database as a 'BLOB'.

Finally, I recommend that you do not use 'InputStream' in your FormBean, but instead use something like 'MultiPartFile', since you can read an InputStream only once (unless you rewind/reset it). Also, MultiPartFile will give you the filename and length.